# How can I discover that the connection with Mongo was reestablished?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need emit an event when the connection was connected and disconnected. My problem is to detect when the connection was reestablished.

The mongo drive emit um event when the connection was disconnected (on error), but it doesn't emit a event when the connection is reestablished.

```
MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, function (err, db) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error on connecting to mongo!');
    console.error(err);

    reconnect();

    return;
  }

  console.log('Mongo connected!');
  emit('connected', db);   // This event is emitted only on the first connection.

  db.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongo connection broken!');
    console.error(err);
    emit('disconnected');
  });
}
```

Analyzing the code I discovered the serverConfig object.

```
db.serverConfig.on('reconnect', function() {
  console.log('DB reconnected');
});
```

Is it a good practice to use this internal object?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem with using an undocumented internal object, is that it might disappear one day, without you knowing. You could fork the code and expose the event - but then you'd have to maintain the code through versions.

Comment: I agree. My process takes messages from a rabbit queue and saves the data on mongo. If any error occurs the message returns to the queue. When the connection with the mongo is broken the process loops taking and returning the message to the queue. To avoid this so that the connection is broken any other message is removed from the queue and when the connection is established the process back to consume the messages from the queue. So I need to know when the connection is re-established.

Comment: How about setting an application wide flag when the exception is thrown and emit an event yourself after the next successful write when the flag is set?

Comment: Once the connection with the mongo is broken the process does not perform anything until the connection is re-established. I could create a timer that executes a query on the mongo to verify that it came back but I wanted to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

According to Mongo driver developers, it's a good practice to use db.serverConfig to subscribe to the 'reconnect' event.

More details in:
[Database object emits a 'reconnect' event](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-282)